# Deploying flexible GAE takes 30mins+

Tags: google-app-engine, terraform

I have the below terraform code which works but every time I merge to master and run the github action to call `terraform apply` the deployment takes 30mins+. As far as I can see the logs are full of  `google_app_engine_flexible_app_version.myapp: Still creating... [15m0s elapsed]`

and

`google_app_engine_service_split_traffic.myapp: Still modifying... [id=apps/myproject/services/myapp, 13m40s elapsed]`

It's not exactly release often and quickly is it? Is there anything you can see on why this is taking so long?

```
resource "google_app_engine_flexible_app_version" "myapp" {
  project    = var.GCP_PROJECT
  service    = "myapp"
  runtime    = "custom"
  version_id = "v${formatdate("YYYYMMDD-hhmmss",timestamp())}"

  noop_on_destroy = false

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }

  resources {
    cpu = 1
    memory_gb = 1
    disk_gb = 10
  }

  deployment {
    container {
      image = "eu.gcr.io/${var.GCP_PROJECT}/myapp:${var.GIT_SHA}"
    }
  }

  env_variables = {
    ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = var.ENVIRONMENT
  }

  beta_settings = {
    cloud_sql_instances = "${google_sql_database_instance.gps.connection_name}=tcp:5432"
  }

  manual_scaling {
    instances = 1
  }

  liveness_check {
    path = "/liveness_check"
  }

  readiness_check {
    path = "/readiness_check"
    app_start_timeout = "1800s"
  }
}

resource "google_app_engine_service_split_traffic" "myapp" {
  service = google_app_engine_flexible_app_version.myapp.service

  migrate_traffic = false
  split {
     allocations = {
      (google_app_engine_flexible_app_version.myapp.version_id) = 1.0
     }
  }
}

resource "google_dns_record_set" "myapp" {
  name         = "${local.myapp_domain_name}."
  managed_zone = var.DNS_ZONE_NAME
  type         = "CNAME"
  ttl          = 300
  rrdatas      = ["ghs.googlehosted.com."]
}

resource "google_app_engine_domain_mapping" "myapp" {
  domain_name = local.myapp_domain_name

  override_strategy = "OVERRIDE"

  ssl_settings {
   ssl_management_type = "AUTOMATIC"
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have the `google_app_engine_service_split_traffic` if you are just routing all of the traffic to the same app and version?

Comment: Also, why do you need a 30 minute max wait on the readiness probe? It sounds like your application's `/readiness_check` endpoint might not be returning a 200 response and then eventually it hits the 30 minute timeout and rolls back the deployment. I'd check that and I'd also reduce the timeout to something more sensible because I'd be surprised if you really expect your application to take a full 30 minutes to start.

Comment: The app returns fine for readiness, should probably lower the timeout, it checks db connections etc.  Regarding split traffic, when we do a new release it is a new version so it will route to the new version slowly I presume?

Comment: The time issue could either be related with Terraform, container building or cloud services and it would probably need in depth investigation of App Engine logs we can't perform here. I would recommend reaching out to [GCP support team](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/community#file_feature_requests_and_defects)

Comment: Deploying usually takes about 15-30 minutes for me too, while this is not good behavior, I don't think it's incorrect behavior.